# Proving Infinitely Ascending Chain of Subobjects

Tags: category-theory, proof-writing

How would you prove that an infinitely ascending chain of subobjects of an object $X$ in $\mathcal{C}$ is stationary given that only finitely many preorders in the chain that are not isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Could you define or provide a link to those terms?

Comment: @PyRulez https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noetherian+category

Comment: "given that only finitely many preorders in the chain that are not isomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$" What is this part of your sentence supposed to mean?